# TeXstudio libpng error: IDAT: CRC error while compiling

Tags: errors, compiling

I am getting the following error while compiling my .tex file

"libpng error: IDAT: CRC error".

As far as I understand this has to do with corrupted image files. However, I did not add any images after the last, succusssful compilation.
Is there any way to output the line indicating which image might be corrupted? No line is shown by default.
I am using TeXstudio 2.11.0

Thanks in advance for any help!

John

Comment: you can tell the page as tex outputs [1],[2],[3] as each page is shipped out, do you have so many images on each page that determining which image is the problem is tricky after that?

Comment: ok, I just went to the last line in the log that was compiled correctly and found the corrupted file,

Comment: i was not so familiar with the gui and the log yet, but thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can tell the page as tex outputs [1],[2],[3] as each page is shipped out, do you have so many images on each page that determining which image is the problem is tricky after that?